# Efficient way to assign values depending on a column interval for each row

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table

I want to update columns (add 1) depending on a range of values that varies in each row. My attempt at iterating row by row turns out to be slow. I show a little example.

```
M <- matrix(0,nrow = 50*10^3,ncol = 100)
library(data.table)
M <- as.data.table(M)
n <- nrow(M)
set.seed(4234)
M[, `:=` (a=sample(50,n,replace = T),
          b=sample(50:100,n,replace = T))]

for (x in 1:n) 
  set(M,i=x,j=M[['a']][x]:M[['b']][x], value = 1L)
```

Is there any way to gain speed with this calculation?

Comment: Please state `library` calls in code, this time I've helped you.

Comment: What is the context + end goal?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option:

```
cols <- paste0("V", 1L:100L)
M[, (cols) := {
    m <- as.matrix(.SD)
    l <- mapply(function(x,y) seq(x, y), a, b, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
    m[cbind(rep(1L:.N, lengths(l)), unlist(l))] <- 1L
    as.data.table(m)
}, .SDcols=cols]
```